# Loading Dask dataframe with SQLAlchemy fails

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to load a Dask dataframe with SQLAlchemy using `dd.read_sql_query`. I define a table with one of the columns `balance_date` type DateTime (in the database is type DATE):

```
class test_loans(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'test_loans'
      annual_income = Column(Float)
      balance = Column(Float)
      balance_date = Column(DateTime)  # the type of the column is DateTime
      cust_segment = Column(String)
      total_amount_paid = Column(Float)
      the_key = Column(Integer)
      __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint(the_key),)
```

Problem is that the `dd.read_sql_query` fails, as it says that the col_index is not type numeric or date but `object`:

```py
stmt = select([ test_loans.balance_date, test_loans.total_amount_paid ]) 
ddf = dd.read_sql_query(stmt, con=con, index_col='balance_date', npartitions=3)
```

I get

```
TypeError: Provided index column is of type "object".  If divisions is
not provided the index column type must be numeric or datetime.
```

How to fix this? Is this a defect?

Comment: Please can you try and see what pd.read_sql gives for your query, with the dtypes? You will perhaps want to limit your query to the first few rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by casting the column as DateTime in the SQLAlchemy select statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in dask.dataframe, when no limits are given, it fetches min and max values for the index with `pandas.read_sql` which does not parse dates automatically, therefore you end up with this min/max df having object dtypes and that dtype is reused for the division, which cannot accept it.

Here is the culprit code: https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8b95f983c232c1bd628e9cba0695d3ef229d290b/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py#L130

NB. I filled the github issue: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9383

Comment: In pandas.read_sql there's a keyword to tell explicitly what are the date columns. You cannot specify those columns in Dask. I solved this casting the columns as Date.